# Need help on how to use a bootstrap table component in my Angular project

Tags: html, angular5

I just started learning Angular 5 and I found this interesting data table format that I want to use in my Angular project: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/condensed-table-example, especially to get a different color for each label in a column like in the "status" column in the link above.
In this example, labels are hardcoded in the table while in my case I would like to get them straight from my database and display them on the UI(with color variation).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span5">
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Username</th>
                      <th>Date registered</th>
                      <th>Role</th>
                      <th>Status</th>                                          
                  </tr>
              </thead>   
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Donna R. Folse</td>
                    <td>2012/05/06</td>
                    <td>Editor</td>
                    <td><span class="label label-success">Active</span>
                    </td>                                       
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Emily F. Burns</td>
                    <td>2011/12/01</td>
                    <td>Staff</td>
                    <td><span class="label label-important">Banned</span></td>                                       
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Andrew A. Stout</td>
                    <td>2010/08/21</td>
                    <td>User</td>
                    <td><span class="label">Inactive</span></td>                                        
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mary M. Bryan</td>
                    <td>2009/04/11</td>
                    <td>Editor</td>
                    <td><span class="label label-warning">Pending</span></td>                                       
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mary A. Lewis</td>
                    <td>2007/02/01</td>
                    <td>Staff</td>
                    <td><span class="label label-success">Active</span></td>                                        
                </tr>                                   
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

I was thinking about using ngSwitch but I am not sure. Any idea on how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the [ngStyle] directive

considering that you have a users array xD
you could set something like

```
<ul *ngFor ="let user of users">
 <li [ngStyle]="{'background':getColor(user.status)}">{{user.name}}{{user.status}}</li>
</ul>
```

and do an function like this in your TS

```
getColor(status){
    switch (status){
        case "Inactive":
           return 'gray'; 
        case "Banned":
           return 'red';
        case "Active":
           return 'green';
}
```

and lets say

```
users: any[] = [
{
    "name" : "The First dude",
    "status" : "Banned"
},
{
   "name" : "The second one",
   "status" : "Active"
}
];
```

in that case every time that an user is called, the function getColor will be triggered and will return a color to the background of the

:P

Sorry about my english xD i have a lot to learn